# Why do characters in the Dragonball universe continually act surprised at super human feats?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

This is a world  where aliens visit Earth and cause mass destruction, fly and shoot energy blasts, and where the twenty-something protagonist fought as a child in world-wide martial arts competition where humans blew up the moon (Roshi) and flew (Tien) and a demon shows up to compete. Oh, and giant magic dragons darken the skies over populous cities.

Yet even in e.g. the Buu Saga people are stunned by Vegeta destroying the punching strength machine, Trunks and Goten flying and fighting with ki blasts, etc. I've watched some episodes of the show and read some of the manga but I don't understand why all the normal people continue to act the way people of *this* world would when encountering super human abilities when they've had at least 30 years to get used to them.

Comment: It's probably something of a trope, something that makes Dragon Ball, Dragon Ball, but it also could add elements of suspense (or comedy?) despite how unrealistic it may be. I haven't watched in a long long time...

Comment: @DarthLocke oh I totally get the out-of-universe explanation that the shock and awe highlights the awesomeness of the protagonists but in-universe it seems really hard to justify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Satan is probably responsible for much of it. Not only does he take credit for the work of the super-humans, he tries to explain their incredible feats away as special effects and stage magic (i.e. fake).

The fact that ordinary people keep turning up to those martial arts tournaments expecting to win, where they are hopelessly outclassed, suggests that they believe him. They probably assume that stuff like the Moon being blown up was a stunt.

Most people will have seen that stuff on TV, rather than personally witnessing it. They probably think they have a huge fake news problem, until at some point it dawns on them that this stuff is actually happening.